# Not installable dependencies when trying to install blender on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, blender

I did the following to install blender:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

And got this message about unmet dependencies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 blender : Depends: libboost-locale1.54.0 but it is not installable
           Depends: libopencolorio1 but it is not installable
           Depends: libspnav0 (>= 0.2.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried installing each of the 'not installable' packages and their dependencies manually, but it did not solve the problem. Any help is highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue through Synaptic Package Manager. I had tried reinstalling `libboot-locale1.54.0` from the terminal and everything seemed to go fine, but still got the same error when installing Blender. Then out of desperation I opened Synaptic Package Manager and did a reinstall of the same package and to my surprise it solved the issue.